# Upgrading a DD4T website from MVC3 to MVC4

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, upgrade

We're considering upgrading an existing DD4T website from .NET MVC3 to .NET MVC4.   We understand that we need to update our references to the [MVC4 DD4T package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DD4T-MVC4/) to get this up and running, but I was wondering if anyone out there had done so and found any gotchas whilst doing so?

Answer (score 3):

I did it a while back but it was during development so relatively low risk. There might be a few things I've forgotten.

As far as I remember making sure all your references and web.config settings are right is the main gotcha. DD4T itself doesn't change between the two apart from which references it is built against as far as I'm aware.

Look out for the following appSetting

`<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />`

and make sure you're `bindingRedirects` are in place too and do clean builds to make sure there's no pesky v3 DLLs hiding in any of your bin directories.